# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named kivy.app in Python

Tags: python, kivy

```
import kivy

from kivy import *
#kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !
#from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')
if(__name__=="__main__"):
    MyApp().run()
```

First :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2  
.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install kivy
python -m pip install kivy_examples
python -m pip install Pillow
python -m pip install cython
```

Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
>
>  import kivy
>
>  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\kivy.py", line 7, in <module>
>
>  from kivy.app import App
>
>  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.app'; 'kivy' is not a package
> ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193941/discussion-on-question-by-123s-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-kivy-app-in).

Comment: actually this is might be a bug, I posted this issue to kivy on github, and they closed it as (bug not found). however some users still cannot use kivy for this error nether me.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `pip install kivy` in your python terminal, you may have not installed it.

Comment: this did not change anything

Comment: if you have a virtual environment check it out if you activate it or not